# Sitecore 8: caching for media- images

Tags: performance, caching, sitecore, image-loading, sitecore8

I was having a peek into the caching settings for media in the web.config and found out that something needs some clarification. I found one setting called "MediaResponse.MaxAge". I think this setting is to set the cache expiry to given format "Days.hours:minutes:seconds" and we have set it to seven days "7.00:00:00".

Now, I am confused as the images on our site are loading too slow (checked via pingdom) even after allowing caching to last for seven days. Also, veirfied through fiddler if image cache is set to seven days and it does.

[image: snap from pingdom]

Here is the screenshot that shows the load time for a 6 kb image. !!

Yellow- Wait

Green- Acquired

Implemented a function in a class overriding the ResizeProcessor pipeline:

```
 void SaveStreamToCache(MediaStream outputStream, TransformationOptions transformationOptions, ImageFormat imageFormat, Stream img)
    {
        if (_cacheError > 5) return;
        try
        {
            if (img == null || img.Length == 0) return;// don't save empty data.

            byte[] imageByteArray = ((MemoryStream)img).ToArray();

            HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(GetKey(outputStream, transformationOptions, imageFormat), imageByteArray,
                    null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),
                    Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(e.ToString(), this);
            _cacheError++;
        }
    }
```

GetKey() returns a string consisting of image properties as a url.

```
string GetKey(MediaStream outputStream, TransformationOptions transformationOptions, ImageFormat imageFormat)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SitecoreExtensions.Resources.Media.ResizeProcessor_");


        sb.Append("_MediaItem.Path_" + outputStream.MediaItem == null ? "<NULL>" : outputStream.MediaItem.Path);
        sb.Append("_MediaItem.MediaPath_" + outputStream.MediaItem == null ? "<NULL>" : outputStream.MediaItem.MediaPath);
        sb.Append("_MediaItem.FilePath_" + outputStream.MediaItem == null ? "<NULL>" : outputStream.MediaItem.FilePath);
        sb.Append("_AllowStretch_" + transformationOptions.AllowStretch.ToString());
        sb.Append("_BackgroundColor_" + transformationOptions.BackgroundColor.ToString());
        sb.Append("_CompositingMode_" + transformationOptions.CompositingMode.ToString());

        sb.Append("_IgnoreAspectRatio_" + transformationOptions.IgnoreAspectRatio.ToString());

        sb.Append("_InterpolationMode_" + transformationOptions.InterpolationMode.ToString());

        sb.Append("_MaxSize_" + transformationOptions.MaxSize.ToString());

        sb.Append("_PixelOffsetMode_" + transformationOptions.PixelOffsetMode.ToString());
        sb.Append("_PreserveResolution_" + transformationOptions.PreserveResolution.ToString());

        sb.Append("_Quality_" + transformationOptions.Quality.ToString());
        sb.Append("_Scale_" + transformationOptions.Scale.ToString());

        sb.Append("_Size_" + transformationOptions.Size.ToString());

        sb.Append("_imageFormat_" + imageFormat.ToString());

        return sb.ToString();
```

}

What other settings needs to be applied in order to reduce the wait time ??
Referred [this article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/218124)

All help/suggestions appreciated.

Comment: The MaxAge setting isn't going to make the images any faster to download. It will just tell the browser to cache that image for 7 days so next time it doesn't download it from the server.  There are many things that could affect the download speed of an image in Sitecore - have you got any custom pipeline processors running?

Comment: yes..i have imlemented a logic in resize processor pipeline where i decide if images should be cached.

Comment: Try removing that pipeline to check if it is affecting performance.  In my experience, images coming from Sitecore are usually pretty fast, especially for smaller images.

Comment: You mean to completely remove the pipeline or just my custom code nd let the default sitecore pipeline run.?!

Comment: Just comment out the config that adds your processor so you are testing out of the box Sitecore and you can then see if Sitecore is slow or something in the new code is affecting it.

Comment: I think i got the problem. In this pipeline we had earlier wrote a snippet which transforms images to sizes such as thumbnails whilst caching it. So the wait is due to this method. However, we need this method so as to save the content authors the burden to add two images ie. same image with different size. Updating the method snippet and see if we can reduce the wait time.

Answer (score 1):

We needed something similar. The content editors upload images in large sizes and we use a custom media request to crop/resize and cache those images.
I wrote a [blogpost with sample code](http://www.sitecorn.be/tags/mediarequest/) about it. That should do the trick. This will let you cache any number of sizes for the same image.